# Implement search functionality using Kotlin Paging 3 library

Tags: android-room, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I am using Kotlin Paging 3 library, Flow, Single Activity application, using MVVM (Fragment - PaginDataAdapter + diff util - ViewModel - Repository - PagingSource - Dao). I followed a tutorial on how to implement it and it works like a charm. I get the data from a table using Room, and what I what to implement is a search functionality, but I am stuck and I don't know where to start, I know when one use LiveData, you can use MutableLiveData to be able to reload new data, but I not sure how to implement it with flow and paging, to send a String to be search on the database and shows the data on a recyclerview, it will be the same table on Room.

See this question ([Paging 3 + Binding + Room - data not showing on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067927/paging-3-binding-room-data-not-showing-on-recyclerview)) to see in more details the implementation I did.

Here some code snipped

Fragment

```
class AssetListFragment : Fragment() {
...
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

lifecycleScope.launch {
            //Updates the recyclerView
            viewModel.allAssets.collectLatest {
                assetPageAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
}

}
```

ViewModel

```
class AssetListViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val repository: AssetRepository) : ViewModel() {
...
val allAssets = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 60,
            enablePlaceholders = true,
            initialLoadSize = 200
        )
    ) {
        (repository as AssetRepositoryImpl).assetPagingSource()
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

}
```

Repository

```
class AssetRepositoryImpl(
    private val assetDao: AssetDao,
    private val mapper: ItemDtoMapper,
): AssetRepository {
...
    fun assetPagingSource() = AssetPagingSource(assetDao)

}
```

AssetPagingSource

```
private const val STARTING_KEY = 0

class AssetPagingSource(
    private val dao: AssetDao
): PagingSource<Int,AssetEntity>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, AssetEntity>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)

        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, AssetEntity> {
        // If params.key is null, it is the first load, so we start loading with STARTING_KEY
        val page = params.key ?: STARTING_KEY

        return try {
            val assets = dao.getAssetListDb(params.loadSize, page * params.loadSize)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = assets,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (assets.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    private fun ensureValidKey(key: Int) = max(STARTING_KEY, key)
}
```